# How to install specific gdb (or other) package version using apt-cyg in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, apt-get, gdb

I am trying to install fresh version of `gdb` debugger on my `cygwin` (version that comes with `cygwin` is buggy). Since I need the newest version of `gdb`, I need to use `apt-cyg` to install it.

When I run `apt-cyg install gdb=7.12` I get an error message: `Unable to locate package gdb=7.12`. I also tried `7.12.1-1` and `7.12.1`, but same problem.

Does `apt-cyg` support version targeting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### When I run `apt-cyg install gdb=7.12` I get an error message.

You won't be able to get this version until it is added to Cygwin.

The latest version integrated into Cygwin is `gdb-7.11.1-2`:

> [image]

Source [Cygwin Package Search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=gdb&arch=x86_64)